# What does <P> mean?

Tags: c#

I can understand what this code does, but what is the point of that `<P>`?

```
SPWeb web = context.Web;
output.AppendFormat("Site URL: {0}<P>", web.Url);
```

Comment: In this context it does not mean anything other than <P>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the `<P>` is inside a string literal. This means it is simply part of that string and has no special meaning in C#. It appears that it is intended as an HTML tag.

Comment: Yes, I realised it now, it's code injected to a sharepoint site so it works that way.

Answer (score 1):

That's a paragraph HTML tag.

It will start a new paragraph at the end of the string. The effect is that the next output will start on a new line.

When used like that, it's similar to adding a `<br>` tag to make a line break, but the paragraph also has some margin around it, causing the distance between the lines to be bigger.